# Where does the reported number of native speakers in Ethnologue come from?

Tags: reference-request, methodology, languages-of-china

According to [Ethnologue's page regarding "Chinese, Mandarin"](http://www.ethnologue.com/language/cmn/19), the population of speakers of Standard Chinese is

> 889,000,000 in China (2013), increasing. 70% of Chinese language users speak a Mandarin dialect as L1. L2 users: 178,000,000 in China. Total users in all countries: 1,090,951,810 (as L1: 897,071,810; as L2: 193,880,000).

In the "other comments" section, it notes that

> There are Mandarin speakers in all 56 official nationalities of China, but the majority in China are classified under Han, Manchu and Hui nationalities.

My primary questions here would be: **who proposed that there were 889 million L1 speakers in 2013**, and **how did they arrive at that figure**?

Comment: [This page](http://www.ethnologue.com/about/language-info#Population) might help: _Dates and sources for population data are given where available using the conventions described in How references are cited. Where the word “census” appears as the source, it is generally the national census of the country and is not included in the list of references cited. In some cases the source is a government agency (but not the official census) or another organization. Only when the citation has the form “Author Year” will the source appear in the list of references cited; see How references are cited._

Comment: @lemontree Thanks for the reference. I don't think this covers it, though; the "(2013)" part is not described as one of their three reference styles, so it's either an error, or simply the year for which the source makes the estimation.

Comment: I would assume the latter.